# Angular isUnchanged - why doesn't this always work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen this function used in several examples for form validation but can't find any info/docs/api for it and seems not to work in all cases. Is there an alternative for checking has the object changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen the method in AngularJS [tutorials](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), and its just a custom function

```
 $scope.isUnchanged = function(user) {
    return angular.equals(user, $scope.master);
};
```

The above check i believe is reference match not the complete content.

You can use [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) method to watch any change on object. Also go through [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController) it has properties like `$pristine`, `$isDirty` etc which is specific to form editing. I believe these values are also available on form elements.